# JAVA method overriding and Inner class concepts

Tags: java, inner-classes, overriding

```
class A {    //1st code starts here 
    private void display() {
        System.out.println("A class");
    }
}

class B extends A {

    protected void display() {
        System.out.println("B class");
    }   
}

class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A obj = new B();
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

Output : Test.java:22: error: display() has private access in A
                                obj.display();

```
class Outer{     //2nd Code starts here

    class Inner1{
        private void m2() {
            System.out.println("Inner1 class");
        }
    }

    class Inner2 extends Inner1{
        protected void m2() {
            System.out.println("Inner2 class");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        Outer o=new Outer();
        Outer.Inner1 i=o.new Inner2();
        i.m2();
    }
}
```

Output : Inner1 class

Why compile time error in 1st code while output Inner1 class in 2nd code???

Comment: You can't override private methods

Comment: The visibility of the inner class cannot be greater than that of the superclass.

Comment: Because an enclosing class has access to the `private` members of its inner classes; so class `Outer` in your second example is allowed to access the `private` method `m2` in class `Inner1`.

Comment: @nickzoum the visibility of a super class cannot be greater. A `protected` method in a parent can become `public` in a sub-class e.g. `Cloneable.clone()`

Comment: @PeterLawrey a private method of a parent class can never be overridden in subclass.

Comment: @OP private methods can be accessed only within class which declared them by other members of that class like methods (thanks to that we can have setters which can modify private fields). Nested classes also have access to *all* members of their outer class, including private ones, or other nested types.

Comment: @Blip true, but if its package local, or protected it can be overriden and given more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

The code of the `Outer` class can access any member or method declared within the `Outer` class, regardless of the access level. However, the `m2` method being called is the method of the base class `Inner1`, since you can't override a `private` method.

On the other hand, the code of the `Test` class cannot access a `private` method of a different class, which is why that code doesn't pass compilation.

Comment: You cannot override a private method of a parent class. So the code initially posted is wrong and the error show is incrorrect

Comment: @Blip No, sorry, you're wrong. You *can*  have a private method `m` in a superclass and also a method `m` in a subclass. The subclass method then doesn't override the superclass method; they're just two separate methods that happen to have the same name. Try it out.

Comment: @Jesper I get it you are correct. It is not overriding but is being declared as a new method. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

Because private members are accessible only in class.
when class B extends A private members are inaccessible For B.
In case of Inner classes, An inner class is a member of class and have access to all members of enclosing class.